# AmazonS3 Unable to execute HTTP request listObjects minio

Tags: java, amazon-s3, connection, minio

I am trying to get the list of objects from minio using

```
private final AmazonS3 amazonS3Client;
amazonS3Client
    .listObjects("bucketname", "[path]").getObjectSummaries()).flatMap(....)
```

Bean

```
@Bean
public AmazonS3 s3Client() {

    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                    new BasicAWSCredentials(minioConfig().getKey(), minioConfig().getSecret())))
            .withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration()).withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
            .withEndpointConfiguration(
                    new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(minioConfig().getUrl(), "us-west-2"))
            .build();
}
```

Error

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to 10.177.11.21:443 [/10.177.11.21] failed: connect timed out
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5062)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5008)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5002)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:898)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:872)
        at com.localThread.lambda$startPolling$7ebfd9fe$1(WorkerThread.java:75)
        at io.vavr.control.Try.of(Try.java:75)
        at java.util.function.Predicate.lambda$negate$1(Predicate.java:80)
        at io.vavr.collection.List.takeWhile(List.java:1588)
        at io.vavr.collection.List.takeUntil(List.java:1581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 10.177.11.21:443 [/10.177.11.21] failed: connect timed out
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy149.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1330)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
        ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        ... 48 common frames omitted
```

But when I generate presigned url, it works fine

```
amazonS3Client
    .generatePresignedUrl(new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest("bucketName", "[path]").withMethod(HttpMethod.PUT).withExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000))).toString()
```

This code generates the presigned url fine but listObjects fails with connection timeout. This works fine in local, but when I put it in pod in kubernetes, it fails.

I cannot find out what is the issue?